# Grouping by unique values inside a JSONB array

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb

Consider the following table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE residences (id int, price int, categories jsonb);

INSERT INTO residences VALUES
  (1, 3, '["monkeys", "hamsters", "foxes"]'),
  (2, 5, '["monkeys", "hamsters", "foxes", "foxes"]'),
  (3, 7, '[]'),
  (4, 11, '["turtles"]');

SELECT * FROM residences;

 id | price |                categories
----+-------+-------------------------------------------
  1 |     3 | ["monkeys", "hamsters", "foxes"]
  2 |     5 | ["monkeys", "hamsters", "foxes", "foxes"]
  3 |     7 | []
  4 |    11 | ["turtles"]
```

Now I would like to know how many residences there are for each category, as well as their sum of prices. The only way I found was to do this was using a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT category, SUM(price), COUNT(*) AS residences_no
FROM
  residences a,
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT(jsonb_array_elements(categories)) AS category
    FROM residences
  ) b
WHERE a.categories @> category
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY category;

  category  | sum | residences_no
------------+-----+---------------
 "foxes"    |   8 |             2
 "hamsters" |   8 |             2
 "monkeys"  |   8 |             2
 "turtles"  |  11 |             1
```

Using [jsonb_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) without subquery would return three residences for foxes because of the duplicate entry in the second row. Also the price of the residence would be inflated by 5.

Is there any way to do this without using the sub-query, or any better way to accomplish this result?

#### EDIT

Initially I did not mention the price column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select category, count(distinct (id, category))
from residences, jsonb_array_elements(categories) category
group by category
order by category;

  category  | count 
------------+-------
 "foxes"    |     2
 "hamsters" |     2
 "monkeys"  |     2
 "turtles"  |     1
(4 rows)
```

You have to use a derived table to aggregate another column (all prices at 10):

```
select category, count(*), sum(price) total
from (
    select distinct id, category, price
    from residences, jsonb_array_elements(categories) category
) s
group by category
order by category;

  category  | count | total 
------------+-------+-------
 "foxes"    |     2 |    20
 "hamsters" |     2 |    20
 "monkeys"  |     2 |    20
 "turtles"  |     1 |    10
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Actually my question was a bit contrived, imagine that there is a third column with a price: The query also sums this price. With this answer the sum would be too high, since the duplicate foxes would be part of the sum.

Comment: Well, this is quite different question. But note, this is a matter of interpretation. Why the price should be got once when there are two `foxes` tokens?! I thnik you should just eliminate duplicates in `categories` (on inesert/update stage, possibly with a trigger).

Comment: It should be retrieved once, because the price is per residence. Basically the sum of prices of all residences cannot change. The duplicate entries are used in other processes and cannot be removed for this reason.

Comment: Ok, see the edited answer. Still I have a feeling that your model is inconsistent, but I'm surely too distrustful ;)

Comment: This solution is almost identical to the one I proposed in the question. It seems there is no way around the sub-query. I updated my question to clarify the issue with the prices.

Comment: The queries are similar only in appearance. In my solution there is no need to materialize a resultset from a subquery. Use `explain analyse` for both to see that.